# Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't load after installation on Acer Aspire One

Tags: boot

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 from a USB stick, and deleted the Windows OS on a Acer Aspire 1 - 132 - H14N/W.
Windows was deleted, but Ubuntu doesn't boot - it shows Failed to open \EFI... on the loading screen.
If I remove the usb it appears a screen with a message: no bootable driver.
I tried to use the boot repair from the command line one the live usb - advance option backup and rename Windows EFI files.
When I try to install Ubuntu again it asks if I want to erase Ubuntu 16.04 - I think it is installed, but for some reason it doesn't boot.
What can I do?
The output of `ls -l /dev/disk/by-label/` is:
`total 0`
`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Nov 13 06:04 UBUNTU\x2016_0 -> ../../sda1`

Comment: *Failed to open EFI* means it's an UEFI system and most likely you installed Ubuntu in old BIOS mode. This is what you need to understand: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI and  the answer bellow isn't applicable, BTW.

Answer (score 1):

First of all make a Ubuntu Live CD, and add the output of following command to your Question, it will help us in answering you :

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-label/
```

and

```
inxi -Fxzc0
```

Now go ahead and try to mount the partition :

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

If `cat /mnt/etc/lsb-release` gives you details of Ubuntu, you have Ubuntu in that partition (namely sda1 in your case)

Now what you gotta do is :

```
sudo chroot /mnt

grub

find /boot/grub/stage1
```

Above will give output like : `(hd0,*)` replace * with number wherever used below in your case it will be 1 I'm sure,

```
root (hd0,*)
```

The above line sets the root to be mounted at sda* in your case sda1 the go ahead enter :

```
setup (hd0)

quit
```

Optional : search the output of following command for line named `set root=` it should be having `hd0,gpt*` in your case `hd0,gpt1` now your good to go.

`cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Done, now restart your Computer after removing LiveCD, your existing Ubuntu at sda1 should boot up fine.

Comment: This is not answer. Please wait until you have enough reputation for commenting on questions.

Comment: This is my second account if I may, so sorry for trying to help this guy out guess I'll wait to help him out, until I get enough reputation to join your league again, but be aware I have an Acer Aspire V5-573G and had the same boot issue when I corrupted the Windows partition too 4 months back and you're in my way of helping this guy out.

Comment: No reason to get angry or brake the community rules .. what do you need two accounts for? https://askubuntu.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: @derHugo Will look into merging-accounts link, I'm not angry just was pissed off at that time due to things ongoing in my office.

Comment: @RafaelViana Your Welcome buddy and I have updated my answer, this is exactly what I did for my Acer V5-573G in case you were wondering how it was tested.